# :hover not working on <li> after backgroundColor change

Tags: javascript, css

I have managed to get a `<ul>` to switch display on and off with only a few lines of vanilla JavaScript code but I've run into an issue.

I gave the `<li>` that switches it on/off a `:hover` value (gray in this case). I'm keeping the same color on the `<li>` as the `<ul>` is collapsed. When the `<ul>` display is turned off though, I return it to the same value as it had had previously but the `:hover` value no longer works. Any solutions to this?

This is my JavaScript:

```
function expandIt(obj) {
    obj.nextSibling.style.display = "block";
    obj.style.backgroundColor = "gray";};

function reduceIt(obj) {
    obj.style.display = "none";
    obj.previousSibling.style.backgroundColor = "white";};
```

This is the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="expandIt(this)">ITEM</li>
        <ul onclick="reduceIt(this)">
            <li>subitem</li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Uh...you wrote `onlick`. There's no "lick" event in JavaScript, are you sure you didn't mean `onclick`? (You may want to fix that first.)

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R937E/

Comment: @Serlite thank you! that would be a very unusual way of interacting with your screen indeed. :)

Comment: can you add the css hover properties too?

Comment: @gaurav5430 The :hover is defined in the separate stylesheet, which I did not include here, maybe I should have? Not sure, am new here.

Comment: @RichieFredicson That was my first thought, but I have not found how to add it. Do you know?

Comment: @ath20 please include the hover css also

Comment: ul cannot be child of ul , somehow , the browser must fix this error, and nextSibling cannot reach ul probably wrapped by browser within an li ...

Comment: just add !important to your background colour on hover it will take priority over inline style.
li:hover{background-color:#ff000000 !important}

Comment: and yeah as GCyrillus mentioned you have to put the inner ul into an li

Comment: and make white-space disseaper , so nextSibling is your tag http://jsfiddle.net/R937E/1/ ;)  regards

Comment: Thanks everyone! All solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get this working with the !important modifier in your css. Something like this:

```
ul li:hover {
   background-color:#ccc !important;
}
```

This overrides inline styles

Comment: Thank you, that indeed solved it! Do you know if this has any cross-browser issues?

Comment: !important has excellent cross browser support. IE5.5+, Firefox 1+, Safari 3+, Chrome 1+ all support it although there may be some strange behavior in IE < 6

Comment: You're very welcome - a word of caution though, !important is a nice little trick but shouldn't replace good old fashioned cascading principles where at all possible. Overuse of it can lead to headaches down the road! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

*hover versus inline style*

The solution would be to add or a remove a class name with the styling you want. Due to css specificity, anything directly placed in `style` is going to take precedence over the defined rule inside of your css hover definition. The result is that your hover is never going to register the change of background color.

*issues with siblings*

Another issue with your code is that `nextSibling` and `previousSibling` are going to examine **text** nodes as well as elements. The trick there is going to be to ensure you are looking at an actual element and not a text node.

Something like this approach will ensure you end up with an element (`.nodeType == 1`)

```
function expandIt(obj) {
 var next = obj.nextSibling;
 while(next && next.nodeType != 1)next = next.nextSibling;
 next.style.display = "block";
 obj.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
};

function reduceIt(obj) {
 obj.style.display = "none";
 var prev = obj.previousSibling;
 while(prev && prev.nodeType != 1)prev = prev.previousSibling;
 prev.style.backgroundColor = "white";
};
```

Here is a demo of that concept: http://jsfiddle.net/Yu97H/

Now, even with that working example, it is possible to click so that gray is set as the background, but have hover broken. A simple rule such as `ul li:hover { background-color: blue; }` will exhibit that behavior.

Here is a demo of that behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/Yu97H/1/

Comment: Thanks! That's what I figured was going on but was not sure how to fix it in the most efficient way.